# How to open attachment in Microsoft Office Online?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph to get attachment in mail.

```
GET /messages/{messageId}/attachments
```

Below is a Excel file I got in attachment. It is not shared through SharePoint or OneDrive. It is a real file.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('576552d5-3bc0-42a6-a53d-bfceb405db23')/messages('AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEJAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAEDHFyhAAA%3D')/attachments",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEJAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAEDHFyhAAABEgAQAJNuGUnRZb5Ng3YjQgsDdEg=",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-04-20T18:02:05Z",
            "name": "Book1.xlsx",
            "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            "size": 58818,
            "isInline": false,
            "contentId": null,
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes": "UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAA..."
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is if the attachment is a Excel / Word / PowerPoint file, is there a way to get the link to open/view it in Microsoft Office Online? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, no. In order to open a document in Office Online, it needs to be copied to a storage provider that supports WOPI. The simplest method would be to use the user's OneDrive instance. Once the file has been saved to OneDrive, querying the `DriveItem` will return a `webUrl` property that contains the full URI to open that document in Office Online.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if that file is shared in OneDrive and you attach to the email the shared copy of it in the cloud.
First of all you have to use beta API version to query for attachments:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{messageId}/attachments`

It will return to you the `SourceUrl`. This url you can open in a browser even when you are not logged in.